# How to static compile ps(procps)

Tags: c, linux, makefile, compilation, static

For forensic reason I want to compile some basic tool on Centos like cat,grep,vi,find,md5sum,dir..etc.It's very important to check the process list when we do forensic.so I try to compile ps(procps) statically.and I do failed.
here are the steps I tried:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps.git
cd procps
./autogen.sh
./configure LDFLAGS="-static"

make SHARED=0 CC='gcc -static'
```

also googled so many posts and tried:

```
./configure LDFLAGS="-all-static"
./configure --enable-static --disable-shared
make SHARED=0 CC='gcc -static'  
make -e LDFLAGS=-all-static
export LDFLAGS="-static -Wl,--no-export-dynamic"
make -e LDFLAGS=-all-static
make sense CC="gcc -static"
```

and combination of these configuration with make,none of this working,some compile failed and some success,but when I check it with ldd pscommands,it showed

```
[root@localhost ps]# ldd pscommand
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffca9bc2000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3b078cd000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3b07500000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3b07ad1000)
```

Is procps has some deep dependent on these non static libary?

Comment: Why don't use [busybox](https://www.busybox.net/)? (note: there are exist a lot of kernel backdoor.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compiled for procps-ng-3.3.16 (the latest now), try :

```
./configure \
    --disable-shared \
    LDFLAGS=--static
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install glibc-static.